# How to echo string value from an multi dimmensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can i echo each `hotelCode, totalPrice, boardType` and `roomCategory` from the below multidimmensional array

```
<?php
$hotelCodes = array() ;
$availHotels = $checkAvailability->availableHotels ;
foreach($availHotels as $hotel){
    if (!isset($hotelCodes[$hotel->hotelCode])) {
        $hotelCodes[$hotel->hotelCode] = array();
    }
    // you could ofcourse just take specific info from $hotel and put it in here.
    $hotelCodes[$hotel->hotelCode][] = $hotel;
}
?>
```

and
    `print_r of $hotelCodes` is

```
Array ( [HOTELCODE1] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [processId] => HV-82768336 [hotelCode] => ITULJP [availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation [totalPrice] => 279 [totalTax] => 0 [totalSalePrice] => 298.86 [currency] => EUR [boardType] => Breakfast Buffet [rooms] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [roomCategory] => Twin Room - Non-Refundable-1 double bed [paxes] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) ) [totalRoomRate] => 279 [ratesPerNight] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-11 [amount] => 34.84 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-12 [amount] => 34.88 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-13 [amount] => 34.88 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-14 [amount] => 34.88 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-15 [amount] => 34.88 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 [amount] => 34.88 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-17 [amount] => 34.88 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-18 [amount] => 34.88 ) ) ) ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [processId] => HN-10616086 [hotelCode] => ITULJP [availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation [totalPrice] => 294 [totalTax] => 0 [totalSalePrice] => 314.59 [currency] => EUR [boardType] => Breakfast Buffet [rooms] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [roomCategory] => Double or Twin Room-1 double bed [paxes] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) ) [totalRoomRate] => 294 [ratesPerNight] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-11 [amount] => 36.75 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-12 [amount] => 36.75 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-13 [amount] => 36.75 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-14 [amount] => 36.75 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-15 [amount] => 36.75 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 [amount] => 36.75 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-17 [amount] => 36.75 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-18 [amount] => 36.75 ) ) ) ) ) ) [HOTELCODE2] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [processId] => HZ-21733446 [hotelCode] => ITOI6P [availabilityStatus] => InstantConfirmation [totalPrice] => 295 [totalTax] => 0 [totalSalePrice] => 0 [currency] => EUR [boardType] => Room Only [rooms] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [roomCategory] => Double Or Twin Standard [paxes] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [paxType] => Adult [age] => 30 ) ) [totalRoomRate] => 295 [ratesPerNight] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-11 [amount] => 37 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-12 [amount] => 37 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-13 [amount] => 37 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-14 [amount] => 37 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-15 [amount] => 37 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-16 [amount] => 37 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-17 [amount] => 37 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [date] => 2015-03-18 [amount] => 36 ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

I need to echo the values
HOTELCODE1 and HOTELCODE1 as $hotelcode[1] and $hotelcode[2]
and totalRoomRate, roomCategory and boardType for each hotelcode

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? Sorting and getting unique values are two different things, and you cannot sort anything áfter you echo it, only before.

Comment: How do you determine "unqiue" for a hotel? Do they have an identifier? Is it HotelCode?

Answer (score 0):

You're already there, you just need to make sure only one hotel is stored for any hotel-code.

```
foreach($availHotels as $hotel){
    // if we do not have a hotel with this code yet
    if (!isset($hotelCodes[$hotel->hotelCode])) {
        // store this one there
        $hotelCodes[$hotel->hotelCode] = $hotel;
    }
}

// run over the available hotels
foreach( $hotelCodes as $hotel ) {
  echo $hotel['hotelCode'] . ' -> ' . $hotel['totalPrice' ] . ' -> etc ';
}
```

Comment: You'll have to give me an example of what you want it to look like. Also, if it's only returning arrows then probably there is an error in the keys somewhere. You should turn on error reporting so you can see these things.

Comment: please check the modified answer:

Comment: I need to echo the values
HOTELCODE1 and HOTELCODE1 as $hotelcode[1] and $hotelcode[2]
and totalRoomRate, roomCategory and boardType for each hotelcode